# SWITCH expression must be a scalar or character vector constant

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Apologies for any mistake am still learning programming and also in MATLAB. The code Below is written to satisfy the fact that if the Playerlocation is either ([0, 1, 2, 3]) the case should display the text (You are in a Sunny Field) and I will be adding to it if Playerlocation is not = ([0, 1, 2, 3]) it should display display a different text ( You are not in a Sunny Field) I would appreciate it if am corrected and thanks in advance

```
function describeLocation()
        clear all 
        close all

        global playerLocation;

     playerLocation = ([0, 1, 2, 3]);

    switch (playerLocation)

        case 0
            Text ='You are in a Sunny Field';
        disp(Text);

        case 1
            Text1 ='You are in a Sunny Field1';
        disp(Text1);

        case 2
            Text2 ='You are in a Sunny Field2';
        disp(Text2);

        case 3 
            Text3 ='You are in a Sunny Field3';
        disp(Text3);


    end
```

Answer (score 2):

The input to the `switch` statement must be a scalar or character array (as clearly specified by the error message). In your case, `playerLocation` is an array which causes the error.

Rather than passing the entire array to `switch` you should loop through the array and pass each scalar member separately

```
for k = 1:numel(playerLocation)
    switch (playerLocation(k))
    case 0
        Text ='You are in a Sunny Field';
        disp(Text);
    case 1
        Text1 ='You are in a Sunny Field1';
        disp(Text1);
    case 2
        Text2 ='You are in a Sunny Field2';
        disp(Text2);
    case 3 
        Text3 ='You are in a Sunny Field3';
        disp(Text3);
    end
end
```

To shorten this up, you can include multiple values in your `case` statements

```
switch(playerLocation(k))
case {0, 1, 2, 3}
    disp('You are in a sunny field');
otherwise
    disp('You are not in a sunny field');
end
```

If you're trying to check if `playerLocation` is *exactly* `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, then a `switch` statement isn't what you want. You would just want a normal `if` statement

```
if isequal(playerLocation, [0, 1, 2, 3])
    disp('You are in a sunny field')
else
    disp('You are not in a sunny field');
end
```